# Javascript not working in second html file in Phonegap & jQuery Mobile

Tags: cordova, jquery-mobile

I am working on an Phonegap jQuery mobile Android app. The app starts with the default index.html page and in it i am using $.mobile.changePage to load demo.html file. The demo.html gets loaded and displayed correctly but the javascript isn't working in it. I think i am messing up with the 'pageinit' event of jQuery Mobile or i don't know how to use it.

Here is my code :

This happens in index.html :

```
    $.mobile.changePage("demo.html", {
                                transition: "slideup",
                                reverse: false,
                                changeHash: false
                            });
```

And the code for demo.html :

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
  <head>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    $('#demo-page').live('pageinit', function(){
    alert("Welcome");
  });
  </script>
    </head>
    <body>
    <div data-role="page" id="demo-page" >
    <div data-role="header">
    <h1>Take a tour</h1>
    </div>
        <div data-role="content" id="demo-content">
            <h2>This is the demo page.</h2>
        </div>
    </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

So when the demo.html gets displayed, the 'Welcome' alert doesn't gets executed.
I have no idea what is happening here.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is not working because only body part of a second page is loaded.

Put this part:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('#demo-page').live('pageinit', function(){
        alert("Welcome");
    });
</script>
```

into the index.html.

Only way this code can be executed from demo.html is if it was loaded as an external link.

Comment: Okay great! the alert worked but first the alert worked and then the demo.html got loaded. Any solution.

Comment: Change pageinit to an other page event, take a look at my other article on this thematic: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14468659/jquery-mobile-document-ready-vs-page-events

Comment: Last page event executed is a pageshow, you should probably use that one.